# blender python onchange event

Tags: python, blender

can someone provide a simple way to listen for an event in blender python?
I have a custom select field in the texture panel with options: lightmap, normalmap, bumpmap, map. If the user selects the normalmap, I want to auto check mark the use_map_normal checkbox to True. I cannot figure how to attach an event for this. I cannot do it in the draw method as it produce errors when trying to change any bpy data. Thanks,

Jim

Comment: You might want to try http://blender.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at this forum and found a solution. I had to add an update=some_method in my types definition parameters. Then add the method that it calls to make my change.

Answer (score 2):

When adding a custom property you can specify a function that is called when the property is changed, this function can be used to update other properties.

example:

```
def update_checkbox_dependencies(self,context):
    active_index = context.object.active_material.active_texture.name
    bpy.data.textures[active_index].use_normal_map = True


bpy.types.Texture.THREE_map_type = EnumProperty(name="Map Type",
    items=map_type_array, default=constants.MAP,
    update=update_checkbox_dependencies)
```